# Chaining promises one by one till one return not empty result

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a specific problem with promises - I didn't find any solution for my problem.

I have list of services(classes), for example

```
const services = [
     FirstCacheDataProvider,
     SecondCacheDataProvider,
     // etc, there can be more services, unspecified number of services
];
```

Each class implements methods (for example find) which returns promise(it's resolved inside this method and I don't have access to body of this method. It's obviously asynchronous)

Now I want to call this methods one by one till one return **NOT EMPTY** result.

Is there any way to do this without big chain of then?

Example of workflow:

We have 4 services

```
FirstCacheDataProvider.find() // result of promise is empty
SecondCacheDataProvider.find() // result of promise is empty
ThirdCacheDataProvider.find() // result of promise IS NOT EMPTY
// fourth service's method is not called
```

Comment: idk if `yield` will work for your case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple method would be to use a `for` loop and `await` each service call in an `async` function:

```
for (let i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
  const result = await services[i].find();
  if (result === 'NOT EMPTY') { // or whatever condition you're searching for.. .length?
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope he has the `await` keyword available.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick. I assumed by **NOT EMPTY** you meant other than `undefined` :)

```
const services = [
  FirstCacheDataProvider,
  SecondCacheDataProvider,
  // etc, there can be more services, unspecified number of services
]

// reduce all services to a promise that either returns first value or calls next service.find
services.reduce(
  (pending, service) => pending.then(value => value !== undefined ? value : service.find()),
  Promise.resolve()
).then(firstNonEmptyResult => console.log(firstNonEmptyResult))
```